# Eclipse on macosx: org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found

Tags: eclipse, macos

I had a problem on my macbook pro and a fresh installation of eclipse.
I would like to share the solution I got after some hours of puzzling.

Problem: Starting eclipse Helios does not work. A pop up window appears and suggests to look into the log file `/Applications/eclipse/configuration/<xyz>.log` which contains:

```
!SESSION 2011-07-05 14:05:17.027 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_26
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/alessia/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/alessia/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-07-05 14:05:18.260
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Cause: Seems that a parsing exception occurs, but eclipse eats it and generates only the above useless information.

OS version: 
  System Version:   Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K540)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 10.8.0

My config.ini:

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Mon May 30 12:48:24 CEST 2011
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.java
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Documents/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

Comment: I've been running various versions of Helios on Snow Leopard without issue.  What does `/Applications/eclipse/configuration/config.ini` look like?  Also, what version of OS X?

Comment: Please split this post into two: a question and an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

1. Remove the files `/Application/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.extraData.9` and `/Application/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.mainData.9`
2. Remove any XML parser you have in your shared library folder. In my case I had `xercesImpl.jar` in `/Library/Java/Extensions`. Just to be sure, I moved all the content of the directory in /tmp
3. Restart eclipse
4. Breath...it should work now!
5. Move again your libraries in `/Library/Java/Extensions`

That's all. Hope this can help you!

Comment: Good sir,
I'm having a replica of your issue, but it's not working with me, the 'org.eclipse.core.runtime' directory is empty, and so is the /Library/Java/Extensions .. Can you Please help me ?

Comment: this worked perfectly for me...If hidden files aren't being shown(its not done by default) here's how to do it: http://guides.macrumors.com/Viewing_hidden_files_on_a_Mac

Comment: This was a lifesaver for a Selenium installation that was causing me to be unable to install or run Eclipse. Thank you!